# Replace "eval" in vectors created inside a loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, eval

I created a GUI that requests info from the user, which is then saved into series of variables (e.g. `Fp1`, `Sn1`, `Fp2`, `Sn2`, `Fp3`, `Sn3`...) and into different files (`Info1.mat`, `Info2.mat`, `Info3.mat`...). Once I have collected all of them, there's a vector created inside a loop with the value of each one of them. For example:

```
Fp1=0.8;
Fp2=0.9;
Fp3=0.85;
```

and I want to get:

```
Fp=[0.8 0.9 0.85];
```

I have already tried the following code:

```
for jj=1:1:ng
  Fp(jj)=eval(sprintf('Fp%d',jj));
end
```

which is working fine, but I would like to know if there are other suggestions to do the same without "eval".

Comment: Having the variables `Fp1` to `Fp3` already created, you can't do anything to avoid `eval`. Why do you have to use such variable names? Use a cell array or a struct!

Comment: @Daniel is right. There is basically no situation where you should need to use `eval`. If you find yourself in that position, rethink what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This was one of the first parts I did when creating my GUI and now that I'm checking it I found this situation. Now with what you're telling me, I may change that section. Thank you.